# Use lapply to go through a list of dataframes and change class of specific column

Tags: r, lapply

I'm trying to go through a list that has two data frames and I want to change the class of column 2 from factor to data in each of those data frames.  I can solve this with a for loop, but I want to learn how to do this with lapply.

```
tom <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3), b = c("2017-01-09","2017-01-10","2017-09-11"))
kate <- data.frame(a = c(4,5,6), b = c("2017-01-09","2017-01-10","2017-09-11"))

testList <- list(tom,kate)

f <- lapply(testList, function(x) {
    x[,2] <- as.Date(x[,2])
})
```

I'm looking for f to return the original data frames but with the change in class for columns 2. Instead I get a list with only the dates (not the original data frames).  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to return the 'x' or `list` element in 'f'

```
f <- lapply(testList, function(x) {
      x[,2] <- as.Date(x[,2])
      x
})
```

---

A more compact option without using the anonymous function call is `transform`

```
f1 <- lapply(testList, transform, b = as.Date(b))
```

Comment: Thanks.  both work, but the second one is even better.